# Primefaces update component after <p:ajax listener>

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a selectOneMenu that changes a value in the backing bean and based on that value, another component is being displayed or not. What I would like is to update that certain component after the value in the backing bean is changed by the selectOneMenu

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{backingBean.id.value}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose" itemValue="0"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.idList}"
                var="id" itemLabel="#{id.name}" itemValue="#{id.value}" />
             <p:ajax listener="#{backingBean.changeId}" process="@this" update="userMenu"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
<p:menu id="userMenu" rendered="#{backingBean.id.value != 0}">
</p:menu>
```

The value changes in the backing bean but the  is not updated.

Comment: Is your <h:selectOneMenu /> is wrapped with tag <h:form>?

Comment: Please check if you created the id object in your backing bean, in the declaration or in the postconstruct method. In the declaration would look like ´private Property id = new Property();´.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{backingBean.id.value}" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose" itemValue="0"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.idList}"
            var="id" itemLabel="#{id.name}" itemValue="#{id.value}" />
         <p:ajax listener="#{backingBean.changeId}" process="@this" update="userMenuWrapper"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
<p:outputPanel id="userMenuWrapper">
    <p:menu id="userMenu" rendered="#{backingBean.id.value != 0}"/>
</p:outputPanel>
```